# MERGE COMMAND in SqlCommand in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I'm planning to write a `merge` statement with Visual Studio, but I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near OUTPUT

How can I solve it?

I tried to write the SQL query in `sqlCommando Object but I got an error.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.EMPLOYEE as t
USING dbo.CT_EMPLOYEES as s t.EMPLOYEE_ID = s.EMPLOYEE_ID

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t.EMAIL = s.EMAIL, 
            t.GID = s.GID,
            t.SAP_COMPANY_CODE = s.SAP_COMPANY_CODE ,
            t.FIRST_NAME = s.FIRST_NAME ,
            t.LAST_NAME = s.LAST_NAME ,
            t.COST_CENTER = s.COST_CENTER,
            t.MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID =s.MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID,
            t.SCD_DEPT=s.SCD_DEPT,
            t.LEAVE_DATE = s.LEAVE_DATE,
            t.START_DATE = s.START_DATE ,
            t.CONTRACT_TYPE = s.CONTRACT_TYPE ,
            t.WEEKLY_WORKING__HOUR = s.WEEKLY_WORKING__HOUR ,
            t.STATUS=s.STATUS,
            t.LAST_UPDATE_TIME = s.LAST_UPDATE_TIME 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT(EMPLOYEE_ID, EMAIL, GID, SAP_COMPANY_CODE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, COST_CENTER, MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID, SCD_DEPT, LEAVE_DATE, START_DATE, CONTRACT_TYPE, WEEKLY_WORKING__HOUR, STATUS, LAST_UPDATE_TIME)
    VALUES(s.EMPLOYEE_ID, s.EMAIL, s.GID, s.SAP_COMPANY_CODE, s.FIRST_NAME, s.LAST_NAME, s.COST_CENTER, s.MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID, s.SCD_DEPT, s.LEAVE_DATE, s.START_DATE, s.CONTRACT_TYPE, s.WEEKLY_WORKING__HOUR, s.STATUS, s.LAST_UPDATE_TIME)

OUTPUT $action as Work, inserted.EMPLOYEE_ID, inserted.EMAIL, inserted.GID, inserted.SAP_COMPANY_CODE, inserted.FIRST_NAME, inserted.LAST_NAME, inserted.COST_CENTER, inserted.MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID, inserted.SCD_DEPT, inserted.LEAVE_DATE, inserted.START_DATE, inserted.CONTRACT_TYPE, inserted.WEEKLY_WORKING__HOUR,inserted.STATUS,inserted.LAST_UPDATE_TIME;
```

I get errors about

> Incorrect syntax near OUTPUT

How to solve it?

Comment: What error? SqlCommand works. All other data access libraries (EF, NHibernate, Dapper, etc) work on top of it. In fact, EF Core uses MERGE in a slightly quirky way to batch inserts. If there was an issue, EF Core wouldn't be able to work with SQL Server

Comment: THE ERROR IS "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Output'.'"

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use sqlserver

Comment: `$action` should be replaced to its *value* before executing the query in sql server.

Comment: I dont understand you. please give me a small example?

Comment: I believe `$action` is holding some value in your application code, that value should be present in the query instead of `$action`. Example if the value of `$action` is `insert` then, it should be `OUTPUT 'insert' as Work, inserted.EMPLOYEE_ID, inserted.EMAIL, inserted.GID,...`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `ON` from your merge predicate. Instead of

```
MERGE INTO dbo.EMPLOYEE as t
USING dbo.CT_EMPLOYEES as s t.EMPLOYEE_ID = s.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
....
```

It should be

```
MERGE INTO dbo.EMPLOYEE as t
USING dbo.CT_EMPLOYEES as s ON t.EMPLOYEE_ID = s.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
```